# Midori and webkit2

Tags: webkit, midori

How can I compile Midori to use webkit2 and will it work in Ubuntu 14.04?  I've tried the option --enable-webkit2, but it doesn't seem to be recognised.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [WebKitGTK+ 2.5.1: Good bye WebKit1](http://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2014/08/01/webkitgtk-2-5-1-good-bye-webkit1/) suggests how to build WebKitGTK+ 2 (if it's not already installed / available):

```
cd webkitgtk
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX= -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
make
checkinstall
```

Linux from Scratch [has instructions for building Midori](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xfce/midori.html) with a switch for WebKitGTK+ 2 support, similar to this:

```
cd midori
mkdir build &&
cd    build &&

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  \
      -DUSE_ZEITGEIST=OFF         \
      -DUSE_GTK3=1                \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR=/usr/share/doc/midori-0.5.11 \
      ..  &&
make
checkinstall
```

You **could** try this and report back. What's the worst that could happen? (I'd suggest using a virtual machine, as I have no idea...)

Please note, I have used [`checkinstall`](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) instead of `make install` to (hopefully) make it easier to get rid of everything again.

[Cross post from elementary OS Stack Exchange (will update if there is new info)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2991/68)